# Issues with upgrading a site from .net 2.0 to 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

I want to upgrade my company website from 2.0 to 3.5. I think it should be fairly painless as all the old methods are still supported (just depreciated) in newer versions of .net. Is that correct?

Comment: What are the "old" methods vs the "new" ones? Yes, methods can change from version to version.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio it should tell you of any problems, although I've never had to change anything when converting from 2.0 to 3.5 as they use the same app pool. Good luck!

Comment: Were there even any deprecations from 2.0 to 3.5? 3.5 is just 2.0 plus libraries, although there was an SP that had minor framework changes IIRC but you'll already have that in your 2.0. Do you really mean update to 4? Or to the new C# language features in 3 (they already run on 2)?

Comment: We did this a couple of years ago. Most of our websites are very simple, most of our Web Services are quite complex, we had no problems with either.

Comment: I don't believe 3.5 deprecated anything in 2.0.  3.0 and 3.5 were a collection of enhancements to the 2.0 framework.  Hence the reason why you have to select 2.0 in the app pool selection for IIS.

Comment: I've upgraded around a dozen different 2.0 websites and I've never had problems either. Now, upgrading from 1.1 is a completely different matter. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We had no issues at all upgrading all of our apps from 2.0 to 3.5

I doubt you'll have any issues because .NET 3.0 and 3.5 are "additive" releases - meaning the core functionality of .NET 2.0 remains the same, these just add features.

This brief article explains it a little more clearly: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133927/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/112107-1.aspx

As a side note, we also had no problems going from 2.0 straight to 4.0.  Microsoft has been doing a pretty good job of keeping the upgrades painless.

I would like to throw in a caveat - if you're using third party components, I can't vouch for how easily they survive the upgrade process, but given the additive nature of the releases through 3.5 I think you'll be fine.

Comment: When you have 200k+ lines of production code, written in VB.NET 2.0, which uses "query" as a variable name in just about every place imaginable, then it will have issues. 

Upgrading to 3.5 or higher will think that "query" is referring to the namepsace "System.Web.Query" and will trigger compiler errors.  This is even worse if your site is doing its logic inline (such as without using Visual Studio) and not using code behind files.

Comment: @Nuzzolilo - Ouch!  Thank the powers that be that I haven't run into that one!  Makes you think about naming conventions and being prescient enough to guess at possible reserved keyword conflicts.  I bet there are other examples like that out there.  Thanks for chiming in!